# How do I set icon for Electron app on Linux(Ubuntu, ...)?

Tags: electron

I have successfully set icon for my electron app on MacOS and Windows OS with the icon file in the build folder, configuration on the package.json.

```
"build": {
        ...,
        "mac": {
            "icon": "build/icon.icns"
        },
        "win": {
            "icon": "build/icon.png"
        },
        "linux": {
            "icon": "build/icon.png"
        },
    },
```

However the linux platform seems to not working.

I also try to create the icons folder inside the build folder(./build/icons) as documented https://www.electron.build/icons.html which then paste the 512x512.png icon to there but nothing change after building the app.

Comment: have you found a way yet, even while running as dev on linux i am only getting the default icon. For windows both dev and built versions have the icons displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

1. The issue is the size, use an icon of 256x256, that will work.
2. If your .icns is well defined, you can also use remove the line `"icon": "build/icon.png"` AND remove the file `build/icon.png` (it seems that Electron prioritize the icon.png above the .icns). But in that case your Windows build will not have an icon (Windows build don't use .icns)m, you could use an icon.ico file for Windows.

I ended up using .icns and also setting icon.png to 256x256.